# Triggering an animation in angular JS on number increment?

Tags: angularjs, animation, css-animations

I have a div with a bound variable:

`<i class="fa fa-check"></i> {{packages.limit}} Packages received`

I have a function in my controller that, among other things, increments "limit"

```
_this.limit = 5;

  _this.addPackage = function() {
     ...
    _this.limit++;
  };
```

The net result here is that the number increments on a click.

I'd like to call dramatic attention to this number when the function increments it maybe change number color, size, wheatver.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for.... add a timeout to your increment and use ng-if to animate.

http://plnkr.co/edit/WZohcGaOM2mXRMJQ0MXj?p=preview

```
$scope.addPackage = function() {
  $scope.wait = 0;
  $timeout(function() {$scope.wait=1; $scope.packages.limit++}, 500);
};
```

And the ng-if...

```
<span class="limit" ng-if="wait===1">{{packages.limit}}</span> Packages received
```